# Office windows in Windows 10 opening extremely small

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, microsoft-office

I have a freshly installed Windows 10 PRO system and MS Office Home&Business 2019. I use a 4K monitor on an Nvidia GeForce GTX 750Ti graphics card (I downloaded the latest drivers from Nvidia).

My problem is that Office programs can start extremely small. That is especially the case with "new mail window" in Outlook. See print screen below:

[image]

The window is actually so small that I can hardly locate on the Desktop and change it's size. It's similar with other programs*, but not as severe as is the case with Outlook's New message window.

Each program I open it feels like the window should be bigger (and also it was bigger when I last used the program). Sometimes even when my monitor goes to sleep (and Windows is locked) the windows of the open programs are smaller when I log back in.

The problem is really frustrating (it's my work computer), because I spent 10% of my computer time resizing windows.

What could be the problem?

*I'm experiencing similar behaviour on my home computer (Windows Home, also 4K monitor), but I do not have Office installed so the problem is less severe...

**I do lot of remote deskop connecting with above mentioned computers (from "home" to "work"), if this is in any way relevant ?

Comment: After resizing the Office window, close it while holding the Control button, and it should remember the size for the next open of the same application.

Comment: tried it already. Only works till computer goes to sleep (locks) for the first time

Comment: You could try in "Programs and Features" to right click Microsoft Office, select Change, and repair it using the Quick method, then Online if required. At worst, uninstall and install might help (if you can). Question: "similar behaviour on my home computer" - what is common between the two computers and which apps show this on the Home computer?

Comment: You can right-click Office application icons from Start menu > More > Open file location, right-click shortcut > select Properties, select the Compatibility tab, check the option Override high DPI scaling behavior, scaling performed by: Application. In later versions of Windows, you can need to click Change High DPI settings to find the option. You can also modify Program DPI setting to have a check.

Comment: @harrymc: since it's a fresh install of Office (on fresh install on Windows) I don't think a repair would do. The same is happening with my other programs' windows (i.e. Mozilla), just not as drastic as in my print screen above. The thing common between both computers is Windows 10 (one Pro other Home) and a 4K monitor - since my other computer doesnt have Office, I notice similar problem with Firefox after computer is going to sleeps (and I log back in)...

Comment: @HerbGu: OK, I changed the setting for Excel and Firefox. I'll let you know, if things act differently

Comment: Is this happening when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: I didnt try safe mode

Comment: now it seems better (since I changed the setting above mentioned for Excel and Firefox)

Comment: Update: windows size (especially Office programs, Mozila and Firefox) stil seem to be random after computer locks and I log back in. Even more when I do remote connections between both computer (RDP over VPN)